# Gratis email boxes filter my contact form emails ; local email box doesn't ; but what if I want a domain registrar email box?

Tags: security, domain-registrar, smtp, spf, contact-page

My domain registrar and my hosting provider are not the same company.

On my shared hosting environment with CentOS, Bash, Apache, PHP and MySQL I host an all core MediaWiki website with a CMS-agnostic backend-fronted contact form I have developed.

---

- Large, widely used, gratis email boxes such as Baidu, Hotmail, Gmail, Yandex and others are likely to filter my contact form emails due to lack of (?) or insufficient configuration of (?) DKIM/SPF DNS records in my hosting environment and the lack of proper MTA configuration for SMTP authentication against these email boxes.
  Such filtering can be so harsh that emails can take hours to reach my Gmail inbox, if at all they reach there (which is extremely rare) but normally they wouldn't arrive at all, neither to inbox directory nor to spam directory.

---

- Local email box on the server environment's domain shouldn't generally filter my contact form emails due to a match between my hosting environment domain and my website domain via proper MTA configuration to allow SMTP authentication, even though my shared-hosting partition lacks DKIM/SPF DNS records.

---

- But, I am not sure I want to host my emails on a website hosting company database at all because if I move to another hosting company **it might be a pain** to migrate emails to the new hosting.

---

So, I was thinking about hosting my emails on an *email box I could rent from my domain registrar* which I find finely priced and an elegant solution to my problem about hosting my contact form emails on my hosting provider's end (possible migration troubles in the future) and to my other problem about sending my contact form emails to large, widely used, gratis email boxes.

If I would rent an email box from my domain registrar, should I still encounter a filtering problem similar to the one I encounter with large, widely used, gratis email boxes?

Comment: To sum it all up: I know its standard to host emails on the same environment of a website, so the receiver and the sender would be the same entity, but if I host emails on my domain registrar itself, can this be similar to host them on my own website hosting environment?

Comment: The important thing is to have SPF set up properly in DNS.

Comment: @Steve given that my hosting plan is shared hosting, I cannot control that ; I am totally under the policy and development of my hosting provider --- My hosting provider is SiteGround, which is a widely used, well venerated hosting company, would you assume they wouldn't have at least SPF for shared hosting partitions? (I don't know).

Comment: You should have access to DNS even on shared hosting.  If you are using cpanel, look for the zone editor.  The important thing is to have an SPF record that includes the IP address or an include URL from the server which is sending the email, irrespective of where DNS is located.

Comment: @Steve thanks ; given that IPs can change (although rare and can happen once in 3 years) I prefer not to deal with this at all; I need something even more stable; if a domain registrar email box would also require me to setup SPF than I think I should just stick with hosting emails on my hosting company email program and ask a new question **Is migrating emails from one hosting company to another can be painful**?

Comment: You are making a bigger deal out of this than it needs be.  IP addresses of servers rarely change.  Migrating emails can be easy, it depends on whether both servers use the same email software.

Comment: @Steve I don't think I make a bigger deal out of this than it needs to be --- I don't want to bet on IP changes, let along if for whatever reason I frequently move between hosting providers; I don't want to risk losing even one lead/potential customer so I want the safest email option I can get. `Migrating emails can be easy, it depends on whether both servers use the same email software` and if they don't, that's for another discussion of course.

Comment: Migrating emails is usually hard when you have lots of mailboxes.  If it is just you, you can use any IMAP email client, set up both accounts, and drag the emails from one to the other.  It doesn't matter if the hosts are running the same software or not.   Pretty much all hosts support IMAP.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the IP address of your web host changing.  It would typically only change if you move hosting providers.   In that case you would need to make DNS changes to point to the new web host.   Changing DNS records for SPF would be part of a host migration.

Comment: Also, why limit yourself to your domain registrar for email hosting.   You can host your email with any company.  To run a website with email, you need four hosts: domain registrar, dns host, web host, email host.   In some case all four could be done by the same company, but it often makes sense to have all four of them done by different companies.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have want to work **just** with a domain registrar and a web hosting; working with three or more companies would be, for me personally, an overkill; logistically and financially. I do consider a situation were the domain registrar to takes care of domain registration and DNS hosting, and the web hosting company to takes care of web host and email host. `why limit yourself to your domain registrar for email hosting?` Because I am much more unlikely to change my domain registrar than to change my hosting company...

Comment: I've never seen a domain registrar offer a bundled deal for domain registration and email hosting.   From a financial standpoint, your domain registrar is likely to charge you more for email hosting than some other third party.   I'm not saying that using your domain registrar is always the wrong choice, but you usually want to be able to use the company for each service that provides you the most value rather than be tied into sub-par service and higher prices because you don't want to deal with an extra company or two.   The logistics of working with multiple companies are not complicated.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I nicely disagree; I already work with several companies on several contexts as a freelancer and already handle enough passwords and bureaucracy; because **I can** host emails on my hosting provider's end without opening an email account on my domain registrar, I find no reason to complicate the process with a third let along third and fourth company/companies.

Comment: But anyway that's not my main concern, my main concern is to guarantee that if indeed I would choose to create an email box on my domain registrar instead on my web hosting provider than I wouldn't get similar brutal filtering as I can get with generally any large, widely-used gratis email client such as Gmail.

Comment: I just don't want to pay for an email box on the domain registrar end, and then get frustrated that emails don't arrive due to harsh anti-spam filters which mistakenly recognize emails from my contact form as "spam".

Comment: If you don't set up SPF, most email providers are likely to filter it into spam.   Part of running an email service these days is effective spam filtering.  Customers expect it.  As Steve pointed out, setting up SPF and DKIM is the easiest route forward for you.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without knowing exactly what company you are planning to have host your email.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't want to configure DKIM/SPF/MTA; I leave it for infrastructure developers (which I am not one of) and either way my hosting is FasS/PaaS (shared) so I don't deal with that. Well, than, it seems my best bet is to keep emails on my web hosting environment and not on my domain registrar or a third party (such as Gmail).